# Convert Bytes To Image

Tags: c#

How can I convert bytes of Image to an Image?

Comment: Is there a particular format that you're converting to or any particular properties you want it to have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to wrap the byte array in a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and then use [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Cripes you're fast on the ball with these.  That was less than 30 seconds!

Comment: It's silly that that function is on the `Image` class, while the actual returned images are `Bitmap` objects.