# Creating Image from byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a .NET student trying to learn how to fetch a Image from the database (varbinary(MAX))and convert it to a image file. I have succesfully managed to convert a image to byte[] and save it to the database. This is my code so far trying to get the image back:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var kund = DbContext.Kunder.SingleOrDefault(p => p.KundId == 2);
        byte[] byteImage = kund.Bild;

        Image image = byteArrayToImage(byteImage);

        return View();
    }

    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

The problem  I have that I know of is that Visul Studio is telling this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0117  'Image' does not contain a definition for
>   'FromStream'  ImageToDB..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0  D:\Kay\ASP.NET
>   MVC\ImageToDatabase\ImageToDB\src\ImageToDB\Controllers\HomeController.cs 40  Active

This is the Image class from  namespace System.Drawing (not my own class):

```
namespace System.Drawing
{
    public abstract class Image
    {
        protected Image();
solution
        public delegate bool GetThumbnailImageAbort();
    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",

  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

When I look at diffrent examples on the web I often see this solution, but when I try to use it the FromStream gets a red squiggly.

Tell me if there is anything more you would like to see from my code and I will bring it.

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: When you say "This is the Image class" - do you mean you've created your own Image class? If so, don't do that... if not, please clarify. (Also, please state which version of .NET you're targetting. It looks like it's .NET Core, but which version?)

Comment: Question is, which Image are you using. I cannot see your 'use' definitions. Are you sure it's Image from System.Drawing ?

Comment: Sorry. I did not create that class. Will clarify that

Comment: Here are my usings:  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ImageToDB.Data;
using ImageToDB.Models;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;

Comment: Had to add "System.Drawing-dotnet-core": "1.0.2" manually in Project.Json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Bytes To Image In C sharp net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623198/convert-bytes-to-image-in-c-sharp-net)

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid question is related to .NET Core and not .NET, they are different and same answer does not apply to both.

Comment: Does FromStream exist in .NET and not .NET Core. If so is there a another method to use?

Comment: Again, which *version* of .NET Core are you targeting? What dependencies do you have? Ideally, provide your project.json file and a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the question with my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

i crack the case. My solution.

```
   public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var kund = DbContext.Kunder.SingleOrDefault(p => p.KundId == 1);
        //byte[] byteArray = DbContext.Kunder.Find(kund).Bild;
        byte[] byteImage = kund.Bild;


        return File(byteImage, "image/jpg");
    }
```

View

```
     @model ImageToDB.Models.Kund

 <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new { id = Model.Bild})" />
```